# Having trouble finding inverse of these functions

Tags: inverse-function, data-analysis

New to Maths Stack Exchange. So I have these two peculiar functions:

$$x=L_c\left[\operatorname{coth}\left(2 \beta F L_p\right)-\left(2 \beta F L_p\right)^{-1}\right]\left(1+\frac{F}{K}\right)$$

$$
x=L_c\left[1-\frac{1}{2}\left(\beta F L_p\right)^{-1 / 2}+\frac{F}{K}\right]
$$

Which I am trying to find hard time finding the inverse of each of these i.e finding F(x) instead x(F) as given in these equations.

Are there any tips? I do recognize that first question might be Transcendental equation thus I would assume approximation would be a better approach (with taylor expansion on trig identity ?).

I am trying to do curve fitting of the inverse of these functions to determine the parameters of $L_c$ $L_p$ and K. $\beta$ is given.

Comment: You can rewrite the second equation as$$x = a + \frac b{\sqrt F} + cF \implies c^2 F^3 - 2c(x-a)F^2 + (x-a)^2F - b^2 = 0$$(isolate $\sqrt F$ then take squares on both sides) then use the cubic formula to solve for $F$.

Comment: The firsr of these almost surely needs numerical methods. That might be your best choice for the second even though @user170231 notes that the cubic formula will do the job.

Comment: @user170231 is that the somewhat related to Cardano's method ?